# Problema en matriz de "buscaminas" en java?

Tags: java, array

Buenas, les explico la situación, no soy un experto en programación y soy un estudiante nobel en lo que se refiere a programar, apenas tengo 3 o 4 meses en un grado superior de programación y hago lo que puedo. Nos dieron para navidades un pequeño proyecto de recrear el mítico juego "buscaminas"

El cual me pareció buena idea y estoy intentando  hacerlo, pero tengo un pequeño problema. Despues de hacer los basicos del juego, como generar minas, generar el tablero segun la difilcutad elegida,etc etc, el momento en el que el usuario inserte una coordenada (lo hacemos desde consola) deberá mostrarse alrededor de esta coordenada las minas que hay mediante numeros(contadores), hice dos casillas con estos numeros pero me di cuenta de un error fatal:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1"

basicamente este error dice que se sale de la matriz porque he programado las "numeros contadores" que cuenten las minas que tienen a su alrededor(reglas del juego) y el problema ocurre cuando intentan contar las minas a su alrededor cuando estan al borde de la matriz, es decir cuando matriz[0][0] o parecidos...
Les dejo el codigo a ver si encontramos alguna solucion...

```
package buscaminas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuscaMinas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        System.out.println("Cual es tu nombre?");
        String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Suerte, " + nombre);
        boolean levelOne = false;
        boolean perdido = false;
        char[][] matriz = null;
        char[][] matrizMinas = null;
        int numeroMinas = 0;
        do {
            mostrarMenu(nombre);
            System.out.println("Elija opcion");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1 Para nivel principiante (8 × 8 casillas y 10 minas)");
                    System.out.println("2.-Para nivel intermedio (16 × 16 casillas y 40 minas)");
                    System.out.println("3.-Para nivel experto (16 x 30 casillas y 99 minas)");
                    int x = teclado.nextInt();
                    if (x == 1) {
                        matriz = new char[8][8];
                        matrizMinas = new char[8][8];
                        numeroMinas = 10;
                    }
                    if (x == 2) {
                        matriz = new char[16][16];
                        matrizMinas = new char[16][16];
                        numeroMinas = 40;
                    }

                    if (x == 3) {
                        matriz = new char[16][36];
                        matrizMinas = new char[16][16];
                        numeroMinas = 99;
                    }
                    if ((x > 3) || (x < 0)) {
                        System.out.println("Introduciste opcion incorrecta");
                    }

                    levelOne = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (levelOne == false) {
                        System.out.println("Debes eligir la difilcutad primero, saliendo...");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        generarTablero(matriz);
                        generarTablero(matrizMinas);
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if (levelOne == false) {
                        System.out.println("Debes eligir la difilcutad primero, saliendo...");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        imprimirTablero(matriz);

                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    int randomX = 0,
                     randomY = 0; //declaramos 2 variables que la maquina rellenará con el math random, de esta forma conseguimos rellenar el trablero de minas
                    generarMinas(randomX, randomY, matrizMinas, numeroMinas);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (levelOne == false) {
                        System.out.println("Debes eligir la difilcutad primero, saliendo...");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        imprimirTablero(matrizMinas);

                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    int cordX,
                     cordY;
                    if (levelOne == false) {
                        System.out.println("Debes eligir la difilcutad primero, saliendo...");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("En que fila?");
                        cordX = teclado.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("En que columna?");
                        cordY = teclado.nextInt();
                        perdido = apuntarDatosTablero(cordX, cordY, matriz, matrizMinas, perdido);
                        if (perdido == true) {
                            System.out.println("Perdiste la partida fill de puta");
                            opcion = 0;
                        } else {
                            comprobarCercaniaMinas(cordX, cordY, matriz, matrizMinas);
                            imprimirTablero(matriz);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

            }
        } while (opcion != 0);
    }

    public static void mostrarMenu(String nombre) {

        System.out.println("1.-Para eligir difilcutad");
        System.out.println("2.-Para generar el tablero");
        System.out.println("3.-Para imprimir el tablero ");
        System.out.println("4.-Para generar minas");
        System.out.println("5.-Para imprimir tablero con minas");
        System.out.println("6.-Empezamos el juego " + nombre + " , deberá introducir coordenadas");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("0.-Para salir");

    }

    public static void generarTablero(char[][] matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

                matriz[i][j] = '-';

            }

        }
    }

    public static void imprimirTablero(char[][] matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

                if (j == 0 || j == matriz.length - 1) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        System.out.print("| " + matriz[i][j]);

                    }
                    if (j == matriz.length - 1) {
                        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " |");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + matriz[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    public static void generarMinas(int randomX, int randomY, char[][] matriz, int numeroMinas) {
        boolean unaVez;
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length && numeroMinas > 0; i++) {
                unaVez = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length && numeroMinas > 0; j++) {

                    if (unaVez == false) {
                        matriz[i][(int) (Math.random() * matriz[0].length)] = '@';
                        numeroMinas--;
                    }
                    unaVez = true;

                }
            }
        } while (numeroMinas > 0);

    }

    public static boolean apuntarDatosTablero(int cordX, int cordY, char[][] matriz, char[][] matrizMinas, boolean perdido) {
        if (matriz[cordX][cordY] == '#' || matrizMinas[cordX][cordY] == '@') {
            if (matrizMinas[cordX][cordY] == '@') {
                System.out.println("Hay una bomba,has perdido");
                perdido = true;
                return perdido;
            }

            if (matriz[cordX][cordY] == '#') {
                System.out.println("Ya introduciste en esa casilla");

            }

        } else {
            matriz[cordX][cordY] = '#';
            System.out.println("No hay bomba, ahora se escribe");

        }
        return perdido;
    }

    public static void comprobarCercaniaMinas(int cordX, int cordY, char[][] matriz, char[][] matrizMinas) {
        int contA1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

                if (i == cordX - 1 && j == cordY - 1) { // A1
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        } else {
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j - 1] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j + 1] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    //Transformacion ASCII llamada metodo , dentro de un metodo...
                    matriz[cordX - 1][cordY - 1] = (char) transformacionAscii(contA1);
                }
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                contA1 = 0; //reiniciamos contador...
                if (i == cordX - 1 && j == cordY) { // B1
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j - 1] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i - 1][j + 1] == '@') { // 1
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j - 1] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i][j + 1] == '@') { // 2
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j - 1] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] >= 0 || matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] <= matrizMinas.length) {
                        if (matrizMinas[i + 1][j + 1] == '@') { // 3
                            contA1++;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    //Transformacion ASCII llamada metodo , dentro de un metodo...
                    matriz[cordX - 1][cordY] = (char) transformacionAscii(contA1);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static int transformacionAscii(int cont) {

        if (cont == 0) {
            cont = 48;

        }
        if (cont == 1) {
            cont = 49;
        }
        if (cont == 3) {
            cont = 50;
        }
        if (cont == 4) {
            cont = 51;
        }
        if (cont == 5) {
            cont = 52;
        }
        if (cont == 6) {
            cont = 53;
        }
        if (cont == 7) {
            cont = 54;
        }

        return cont;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sólo deberías comparar las coordenadas que te pasa el usuario con los topes del tablero no? Quiero decir, si te pasa 0 no mires el -1 y si te pasa n (siendo n la longitud de la matriz) no mires n+1

Comment: Hola Jarvan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Ya que sabes a qué se debe, ¿has probado algo para evitar comprobar celdas de fuera de los bordes? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias me has dado una idea :)!

Comment: @Jarvan Jarvebcio Consulta lograste resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Se que la pregunta es vieja pero puede que ayude a otros. Yo lo que hice fue, si el tamaño del juego era 9x9, entonces creaba una matriz de 11x11, y así si la mina estaba en 0x0, pues iba a empezar en 1x1, y así rellenar el alrededor de numeros es más facil.

Este es un ejemplo de cómo hacer los números a los lados, ya solo es cuestión de que usted los muestre a su manera.

```
boolean CuadrosMinas[][] = new boolean[11][11]; //los que estén en true tienen mina

int CuadrosNumeros[][] = new int[9][9];

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
    if(Cuadros[i][j] == true){
      CuadrosMinas[i][j]++;
      CuadrosMinas[i][j+1]++
      CuadrosMinas[i][j+2]++
      CuadrosMinas[i+1][j]++;
      CuadrosMinas[i+1][j+2]++
      CuadrosMinas[i+2][j]++
      CuadrosMinas[i+2][j+1]++;
      CuadrosMinas[i+2][j+2]++
    }
  }
}
```

porque lo que dice @Pablo Simón DiEstefano, es difícil de programar.